# How to resize different blocks in latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, resize

I am trying to create a template like in this image.
[image]

And for this i have this code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\newcommand\Block[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}% delete
\fbox{% delete
\begin{minipage}[c][.2\textheight][t]{0.5\textwidth}
#1\par #2
\end{minipage}%
  }% delete
}

\newcommand\nBlock[2]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}% delete
    \fbox{% delete
        \begin{minipage}[c][.2\textheight][t]{0.5\textwidth}
            #1\par #2
        \end{minipage}%
    }% delete
}

\newcommand\nnBlock[2]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}% delete
    \fbox{% delete
        \begin{minipage}[c][.2\textheight][t]{0.5\textwidth}
            #1\par #2
        \end{minipage}%
    }% delete
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\Block{text}{caption}%
\Block{text}{caption}%
\par\nointerlineskip\noindent
\nBlock{text}{caption}%
\nBlock{text}{caption}%
\par\nointerlineskip\noindent
\nnBlock{text}{caption}%
\nnBlock{text}{caption}%
\end{document}
```

And right now my result is:
[image]

How can i do to give for each row and for each box a specific length. I don't want this boxes to be equal like now.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that something like the following should suit your needs; the first argument to `\Block` is the fraction of the text height, the second is the fraction of the text width; then title and text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\newenvironment{blocks}
  {%
   \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
   \setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}%
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
   \newcommand{\newblocks}{\par\nointerlineskip}%
  }
  {\par}
\newcommand{\Block}[4]{%
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr#1\textheight-2\fboxrule][t]{\dimexpr#2\textwidth-2\fboxrule}
    #3\par #4
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{blocks}
\Block{0.2}{0.3}{text}{caption}
\Block{0.2}{0.7}{text}{caption}
\newblocks
\Block{0.3}{0.5}{text}{caption}
\Block{0.3}{0.5}{text}{caption}
\newblocks
\Block{0.2}{0.4}{text}{caption}
\Block{0.2}{0.6}{text}{caption}
\end{blocks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's what i want but now i have some problems when i add a table in a block. I hope i can solve it. Thanks :)